# Where to find "bug free" html to wiki converter

Tags: wiki, wikipedia

While googling for it.I've stumbled upon html2wiki that seems to do the job(will try after done posting the Q up).  But, other than that, there are many other choices popped out during the query session.

An word on which app to choose would be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: "Bug free" was unnecessary, the majority of software will have some kind of bug.

Comment: @Pixel Developper We understand what it means: a level of bugs as low as you can use the software.

Answer (score 8):

I'm quite a fan of [pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/).  The advantage is you learn one tool and then you can do lots of different kinds of conversions, fast.

Answer (score 5):

This is the only one that has worked for me:

https://foliovision.com/seo-tools/pandoc-online

My use case was an HTML exported from EverNote which I needed to transfer into MediaWiki engine.

Comment: Thanks. this works best so far for me.

Comment: Thanks for the mention. We're the publishers of that tool. To get good wikitext out, I found it works better to convert my Markdown text to HTML and then convert the HTML to wikitext. The conversion isn't fabulous as the references don't end up at the bottom of the article but in the middle. I loath wikitext, it's really a headache. I don't know why Wikipedia doesn't just offer a Markdown interface for editing for less technical authors/editors.

Comment: @Foliovision Well, in part, because you can't express even a **tiny fraction** of the things Wikitext supports using MarkDown. (And no, I'm not even talking about templates, though they'd have to be in the mix as well and you'd still have their syntax.) With a more robust markup language (AsciiDoc or ReStructuredText), you could maybe get _sorta_ close, but MarkDown is far, far too limited to even be a consideration. The conversion to MarkDown would be lossy. Even the unchanged MarkDown wouldn't _remotely_ resemble the original, when converted **back** to Wikitext.

Comment: Wikitext is too complex. But wiki people revel in the complexity. Many of the more intelligent and well-educated people in the world can't bear to use such a broken and overly complex editing system, so Wikipedia attracts a certain kind of nitpicking, shallow intellect.

Answer (score 2):

You could try [HTML-WikiConverter](http://search.cpan.org/~diberri/HTML-WikiConverter-0.61/)

Answer (score 2):

It can be done with [**marksy.arc90.com**](http://marksy.arc90.com)

> [Marksy](http://marksy.arc90.com) is an online (or a Chrome Extension) that converts one markup
> language to another in your browser.

Currently:

> **Input types supported**
>
> - Markdown
> - Rst
> - Textile
> - Html
> - Mediawiki
> - Jira (confluence)
> - Github (gfm)
>
> **Outputs**
>
> - Markdown
> - Rst
> - Textile
> - Html
> - Jira (confluence)
> - Googlecode
> - Jspwiki
> - Moinmoin
> - Trac
> - Mediawiki

Marksy even has an [API available](http://marksy.arc90.com/learn).

Comment: JIRA (confluence)? Both have vastly different syntaxes. Which is it?

Comment: Dead link now...

Answer (score 0):

The best of three test was achieved by [Seapine {Labs} HTML to Wiki Converter](http://labs.seapine.com/htmltowiki.cgi).

It uses AJAX to convert HTML source code to MediaWiki syntax.

The project documentation can be found [here](http://labs.seapine.com/wiki/index.php/Html_to_Wiki).

Comment: Dead link now...